# Anylogic retrieve occupied gate location

Tags: anylogic, warehouse

There is Distribution Center model on the Cloud that a little bit hard to understand for a novice user. I need to understand how to retrieve gate location where the Truck is parked. So that forklift knows where the pallets are to pickup. [Anylogic scheme and blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEBcM.png)

All trucks comes from the same `source`, then `seize` one of 3 gates and `move` there for unloading. Now forklift needs to move there to unload pallets to a specific location. If I'm using `split` then I need to specify location of the pallets for a transporter to pick it up, but I don't understand how to retrieve truck location.

In reality there will be more than 3 gates for unloading.

Answer (score 0):

Truck location is stored in `Truck.dock` and updated in `Main.seizeLoadingDock` upon seizing a Dock agent.

This is how they track the truck location. Each `Dock` agent has several parameters of type Node that specify specific spatial points for the given dock.

You should probably study some simpler example models to understand this better, it is a useful powerful object-oriented approach :)

Comment: Good detailed documentation define best companies, limited tutorial documentation where company officially says - Go and reverse engineer our models, - defines bad go to market approach for the company. (`There are hundred of models in AnyLogic Cloud created by us, we are not able to provide such manuals for each model. Instead, there are generic tutorials which describe the approaches used in models. It is not only built-in tutorials, but also how-to videos on YouTube and posts in our blogs. Using the materials one can` **decompose** `and learn every example model.`)

Comment: ok, but I hope my answer helped you? If so, please mark it as "useful" (up-arrow next to the answer) so future people can also benefit and find it fast :). PS: I am not working for AnyLogic ;-)